How can I register a service based on whether Development or Production?
In Startup.cs I can check if the app in development or product in the following method:
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    { }
    else
    { }
}

How can I do the same check in the ConfigureServices method?

What ASP.NET Core version are you targeting? There's no Startup.cs in ASP.NET Core any more (unless you're targeting ASP.NET Core 5) and the environment is available through WebAppicationBuilder.Environment. You have use a special flag when creating a project to use the old-style Startup class

You can use the IWebHostEnvironment interface within ConfigureServices method in your Startup.cs or Program.cs file.
Example :
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Common services
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        if (_env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // Development-specific services
            services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
        }
        else if (_env.IsStaging())
        {
            // Staging-specific services
            services.AddRazorPages();
            // Add other staging-specific services
        }
        else
        {
            // Production-specific services
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddHsts(options => options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(30));
            // Add other production-specific services
        }
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
    }   
}


Is this what you're looking for?
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(builder => { })
    .ConfigureServices((ctx, services) =>
    {
        if (ctx.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {

        }   
    });

Alternatively, if you must use that Startup class of yours then you should be able to resolve an instance of IWebHostEnvironment/IHostEnvironment via the constructor

In development environment, you mostly build with DEBUG configuration. Hence, it would be approximately the same to check if the source code is built with DEBUG configuration.
To check that, you can use preprocessor directives like this:
#if DEBUG
        // your code for development env. 
#else
        // your code otherwise.
#endif


However, note that this check is done at comepile time. The above syntax actually impacts the source code being built.
For more convenience, you can have such utility class:
public static class BuildConfiguration
{
    public static bool IsDebug()
    {
#if DEBUG
        return true;
#else
        return false;
#endif
    }


    public static bool IsRelease()
    {
#if DEBUG
        return false;
#else
        return true;
#endif
    }
}


I've copied that utility class, from the open source bitplatform boilerplate.
